# Preserve space when stripping HTML with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = "<html><p>Para 1. Words</p><p>Merge. Para 2<blockquote>Quote 1<blockquote>Quote 2</p></html>"
print html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print u''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

The out put of this code is "Para 1 WordsMerge. Para 2Quote 1Quote 2".

I don't want the last word of paragraph one merging with the first word of paragraph two.
eg. "Para 1 Words Merge. Para 2 Quote 1 Quote 2".
Can this be achieved using the BeautifulSoup library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just join the pieces with a space:

```
print u' '.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

Answer (score 18):

And if you are using [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) in version 4.x:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
...
soup.get_text(" ")
```