# Text inside different div tags gets joined without whitespaces

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scraped part of an html file and turned it into a BeautifulSoup object. I want to get its text content but when there are adjacent div tags, they get joined without whitespaces, which is annoying and doesn't sound reasonable to me.
For example:

```
BeautifulSoup('<div>Hello</div><div>World</div>').get_text()
```

This gives you `HelloWorld`, not `Hello World` or something.
How can I fix it?

Comment: The get_text function pretty much just takes away all the tags to leave you with whatever is left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
BeautifulSoup('<div>Hello</div><div>World</div>').get_text(' ')
```

If you use bs4 then you can add a parameter of `' '` in get_text. For more solutions, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072789/preserve-space-when-stripping-html-with-beautiful-soup)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Right. Why did I even make that variable